# Half equations for H2O2 for its reducing and oxidising nature in acidic and alkaline medium

Tags: redox

Is there a complete list of all the half equations for $\ce{H2O2}$ - both oxidation and reduction, in acidic and alkaline conditions? I've looked on the internet but can't seem to find a list with all of them.

These are my first attempts:

- $\ce{H2O2 + 2e^- -> 2OH^-}$ (in alkaline conditions)
- $\ce{H2O2 + 2H^+ + 2e^- -> 2H2O}$ (in acidic conditions)
- $\ce{H2O2 -> 2H^+ + O2 + 2e^-}$ (in acidic conditions)

Are these correct and are there any more?

Answer (score 7):

From [Proceedings of the Symposium on Oxygen Electrochemistry](http://books.google.it/books?id=cptVx_1zpawC&pg=PA198&dq=hydrogen+peroxide+electrochemistry&hl=it&sa=X&ei=k_FhU_zvMoqFtQa1oIDIDg&ved=0CEsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=hydrogen%20peroxide%20electrochemistry&f=false) and [*Water Research* **2002**, *36* (1), 85-94](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0043-1354(01)00235-4):

$$
\begin{array}{lcc}
\text{Formation}&:&~\ce{2H+ + O2 + 2e- &->& H2O2} &\quad E^0=\pu{0.440V} \text{ vs. SCE}\\
\text{Reduction}&:& ~\ce{H2O2 + 2H+ + 2e- &->& 2H2O} &\quad E^0=\pu{1.534V} \text{ vs. SCE}\\
\text{Direct water}&:& ~\ce{2H+ + 1/2O2 + 2e- &->& H2O}\\
\text{Decomposition}&:&  ~\ce{H2O2 &->& H2O + 1/2 O2}
\end{array}$$

($\text{SCE}$ stands for [Saturated Calomel Electrode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_calomel_electrode))

Another strange suggested reaction involves the anion $\ce{HO2-}$ ([Abel E.: Über die Selbstzersetzung von Wasserstoffsuperoxyd. *Monatshefte für Chemie* **1952** *83(2)* 422–39.](http://doi.org/10.1007/BF00938566)):

$$\text{Decomposition 2}:\ce{H2O2 + H2O- -> H2O + O2 + OH-}$$

---

At the cathode occur at the same time the hydrogen gas evolution:

$$\ce{2H+ + 2e- -> H2~} \qquad\qquad\phantom{00} E^0=\pu{0.242 V} \text{ vs. SCE}$$

Meanwhile, at the anode, oxygen gas is evolved:

$$~\ce{2H2O -> 4H+ + O2 + 4e-} \quad E^0=\pu{0.987V} \text{ vs. SCE}$$