# Does hydrogen peroxide in basic medium only give oxygen gas on oxidation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

Does hydrogen peroxide on oxidation gives oxygen gas only in basic medium?

I thought that was true but I read about these reaction of $\ce{H2O2}$ in acidic medium:
$$\ce{2MnO4- + 6H+ + 5H2O2 -> 2Mn^{+2} + 8H2O + 5O2}$$

$$\ce{K2Cr2O7 + 4H2SO4 + 3H2O2 -> K2SO4 + Cr2(SO4)3 + 7H2O + 3O2}$$

What is the possible explanation of both the title and the reactions?

Comment: I don't get it, what would expect when H2O2 is oxidized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both reactions $\ce{H2O2}$ is oxidized by the more powerfull oxidizers permanganate ($\ce{KMnO4-}$) and dichromate ($\ce{Cr2O7^2-}$).

Whether or not oxygen is produced depends on the actual reaction and not necessarily on pH. A rule is that when hydrogen peroxide is oxidized by a stronger oxidant, free oxygen is produced. It is not always the case when hydrogen peroxide is the oxidizing agent itself.

See this discussion: [Half equations for $\ce{H2O2}$](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10375/half-equations-for-h2o2-for-its-reducing-and-oxidising-nature-in-acidic-and-alka?rq=1)